# NodeJS: How Is Logging Enabled for the @grpc/grpc.js Package

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-js

When creating a GRPC client in NodeJS, if I'm using the [`grpc` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc), I can start my program with the `GRPC_VERBOSITY` set to `debug` environmental variable.

```
$ GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug node index.js
```

and I'll get a ton of information about the network communication that's happening.

However, if I switch out implementations and use the [`@grpc/grpc-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) package, `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug` has no effect.

I've poked at the underlying typescript that implements `@grpc/grpc-js`, and I see what look like [logging calls](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/channel.ts#L371).

So my question: How can I enable logging when using the `@grpc/grpc-js` NPM package with NodeJS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/logging.ts#L25):

```
if (process.env.GRPC_VERBOSITY) {
  switch (process.env.GRPC_VERBOSITY) {
    case 'DEBUG':
      _logVerbosity = LogVerbosity.DEBUG;
      break;
    case 'INFO':
      _logVerbosity = LogVerbosity.INFO;
      break;
    case 'ERROR':
      _logVerbosity = LogVerbosity.ERROR;
      break;
    default:
    // Ignore any other values
  }
}
```

Set `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` in uppercase

Also, according to [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/logging.ts#L68), you have to set `GRPC_TRACE` to specify what kind of logs you want to see. To see all logs, you can set it to `all`.

So, In your case, the command becomes

```
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG GRPC_TRACE=all node index.js
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Ayush, I appreciate it. However, running my program with `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG node index.js` with @grpc/grpc-js does not result in any output being sent to the console, whereas using `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug` with `grpc` does result in output being sent to the console.  Therefore this answer, while it contains useful information, doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Can you try `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG GRPC_TRACE=all node index.js` according to [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/logging.ts#L68)?

Comment: Thank you @ayush, `GRPC_TRACE=all` was the missing piece. With that AND GRPC_VERBOSITY U was able to get a bunch of logs.  If you want to add that to answer I'm happy to mark as best.

Comment: What are the possible values for `GRPC_TRACE` and can it be set programmatically?